# 'Python.h: No such file or directory' while building pymedia

Tags: development

When I try to build/install pymedia, I get the following error:

```
    Continue building pymedia ? [Y,n]:y
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'pymedia.audio.sound' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DBUILD_NUM=1869 -DPATH_DEV_DSP="/dev/dsp" -DPATH_DEV_MIXER="/dev/mixer" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DACCEL_DETECT=1 -DHAVE_MMX=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_DVD_STRUCT=1 -DDVD_STRUCT_IN_LINUX_CDROM_H=1 -DCONFIG_VORBIS -DCONFIG_VORBIS -DCONFIG_FAAD -DCONFIG_MP3LAME -DCONFIG_VORBIS -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H -DUDF_CACHE=1 -INone -INone -INone -I/usr/include/lame -INone -I/home/selby/Downloads/pymedia -Isound/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c sound/sound.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2

.7/sound/sound.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
sound/sound.cpp:23:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have no idea what it means or how to fix it, how do I install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cannot install Python modules](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247845/i-cannot-install-python-modules)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the python development libraries installed?
You can do that by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: That still hasn't worked. I can't put the output here, it won't fit.

Comment: @Selby Please add the output in your question, not a comment!